# How to setup maximum lines of ion-label?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm currently creating a new feature for my app. I've set up an ion-list with ion-items in it. These items contain multiple labels and buttons. One of these labels should display a maximum of 3 lines and cut out the rest of the label. 
What should I implement in my CSS that the lines are cut after 3?

I already tried using the 'max-lines' CSS property and several other solutions from users, but none of them worked out for me.

```
.questionText {
    height: 75%;
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
    max-lines: 3;
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

 <ion-item>
      <div class = "leftContainer">
        <ion-label class = "questionHeading">
          Just a random heading
        </ion-label>
        <ion-label class = "questionText">
          This is just a random text which is supposed to cut after 3 lines. To fill this capacity, I will paste some lorem now: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </ion-label>
      </div>
 </ion-item>
```

It's currently showing all lines of the label, which it is supposed to do due to the white-space and word-break, but should cut out after 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line height * number of lines  = max height

```
.questionText {
max-height: 5.4em;
line-height: 1.8em;
height: 75%;
white-space: normal;
}
```